# How can I see which buffers are in diff mode?

Tags: buffers, vimdiff

`:ls` shows my buffers and lists flags for each buffer, but doesn't list whether `&diff` is set.

Plugins like unite's buffer source just rely on `:ls` output.

Is there an easy way to list and manage which buffers are in diff mode (for those times when `:diffget` fails due to more than two buffers in diff mode).

Ideally, I'd like something like `:Unite buffer` that includes 'diff' for buffers with `&l:diff`. A unite source that showed which buffers have certain variables would be cool: `:Unite var diff scrollbind` that works like `:Unite buffer` but appends 'diff' or 'scrollbind' to files with those options enabled.

Comment: Just a reminder that both `:diffput` & `:diffget` take a `[bufspec]` which can be a buffer number or a unique partial filename. e.g. `:diffput foo`. See `:h dp`. Bonus tip: `set diffopt+=hiddenoff` which turns off `'diff'` when a buffer is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
:echo join(
\          filter(
\                 map(
\                     range(1, winnr('$')), 
\                     'getwinvar(v:val, "&diff") ? "window:".v:val."  buffer:".winbufnr(v:val)." -> ".bufname(winbufnr(v:val)) : ""'), 
\                 '!empty(v:val)'),
\           "\n")
```

will return you the information you're looking for.

First of all, `&diff` is a window-local option. This means you can fetch its value with `getwinvar(winnr, '&diff')`, on all windows with `range(1, winnr('$'))`. From there, if true, you have the window number, you can extract the buffer number with `winbufnr(winnr)` and display the name of the associated buffer with `bufname(bufnr)`.

The `join` + `filter` part helps to keep only what matters and print one result per line.